# React native does not wait for the function to finish

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

```
      Listele = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.114/reactapp/Userpage.php', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      } 
      })
      responseData = await response.json()
      global.data= {veri:responseData}
      global.justClicked = 0
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  
  render() {

    this.Listele();
    var cardLists=[]; 
    for(let i = 1; i <= global.data.veri[0]; i++) 
    {
      cardLists.push(
        <ListCard key={i} onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(true);global.justModal=i;}}/>
      )
    }
    const { modalVisible } = this.state;
    return ( ........
```

For loop does not work "undefined is not an object global.data.veri". After reload a few times, it works, but I realized that the function is not waiting. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove loop traversing code from render and create separate method for it like

```
 addCartItems(){
  var cardLists=[]; 
    for(let i = 1; i <= global.data.veri[0]; i++) 
    {
      cardLists.push(
        <ListCard key={i} onPress={() => {this.setModalVisible(true);global.justModal=i;}}/>
      )
    }
  }

Listele = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.114/reactapp/Userpage.php", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    responseData = await response.json();
    global.data = { veri: responseData };
    this.addCartItems(); // add this
    global.justClicked = 0;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```